# How do I distribute points in a text RPG?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, data-structures

I want player be able to distribute 20 "Skill_Points" i thought of doing it by if,elif,else comamnd but i doesn't seem to care about players input and adds +1 "Charisma" no matter.

Btw total beginner in Python 3 and Python for that matter so any tips are welcome.

```
Charisma = 0
Intellect = 0
Strenght = 0
Endurance = 0
Agility = 0
Skill_Points = 20
player_name = input("What's your name? > ")

print("Hello, {}. You are a {}, so become {}!".format(player_name.upper(), "No-one".upper(), "Someone".upper()))
print("Please choose your stats, your class will be determined by distributition of your skill points")
print("Charisma: {}\n""Intellect: {}\n""Strenght: {}\n""Endurance: {}\n""Agility: {}\n".format(Charisma, Intellect, Strenght, Endurance, Agility))
print("You have {} skill points, just type the name of the skill you want to lay your point in".format(Skill_Points))


stat_choise = input("Which skill do you want to upgrade?: ")

if stat_choise == "Charisma" or "charisma":
    Charisma = Charisma + 1
    Skill_Points = Skill_Points - 1
    print("Charisma: {}\n""Intellect: {}\n""Strenght: {}\n""Endurance: {}\n""Agility: {}\n".format(Charisma, Intellect, Strenght, Endurance, Agility))
    print("Skill Poins left: "+str(Skill_Points))

elif stat_choise == "Intellect" or "intellect":
    Intellect = Intellect + 1
    Skill_Points = Skill_Points - 1
    print("Charisma: {}\n""Intellect: {}\n""Strenght: {}\n""Endurance: {}\n""Agility: {}\n".format(Charisma, Intellect, Strenght, Endurance, Agility))
    print("Skill Poins left: "+str(Skill_Points))

elif stat_choise == "Strenght" or "strenght":
    Strenght = Strenght + 1
    Skill_Points = Skill_Points - 1
    print("Charisma: {}\n""Intellect: {}\n""Strenght: {}\n""Endurance: {}\n""Agility: {}\n".format(Charisma, Intellect, Strenght, Endurance, Agility))
    print("Skill Poins left: "+str(Skill_Points))

elif stat_choise == "Endurance" or "endurance":
    Endurance = Endurance + 1
    Skill_Points = Skill_Points - 1
    print("Charisma: {}\n""Intellect: {}\n""Strenght: {}\n""Endurance: {}\n""Agility: {}\n".format(Charisma, Intellect, Strenght, Endurance, Agility))
    print("Skill Poins left: "+str(Skill_Points))

elif stat_choise == "Agility" or "agility":
    Agility = Agility + 1
    Skill_Points = Skill_Points - 1
    print("Charisma: {}\n""Intellect: {}\n""Strenght: {}\n""Endurance: {}\n""Agility: {}\n".format(Charisma, Intellect, Strenght, Endurance, Agility))
    print("Skill Poins left: "+str(Skill_Points))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements have the wrong syntax. You are asking:

```
if stat_choise == "Charisma" or "charisma":
```

but `"charisma"` by itself will always evaluate to `True`, so you will always fulfill the condition for the first `if`. Your statements should look like this:

```
if stat_choise == "Charisma" or stat_choise == "charisma":
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stat_choise == "Charisma" or stat_choise == "charisma"`

## or comparsion strings

`"Charisma" or "charisma"` returns `'Charisma'`

So `if stat_choise == "Charisma" or "charisma":` is always True